# How to hide data when is more than 1 week, Im using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: This is my output in view, but still in there not hiding the redmark.]

This is my controller to display the data from model. In there i put the date + 7days this the expiration i pass into model.

```
public function list()
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $end_date  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . ' + 7 days')); //date expiration
    $data['list'] = $this->list_model->getList($end_date);
    $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('list/index', $data, true);
    $this->load->view('main_layout', $data);
}
```

This is my query in MODEL, Ive use **WHERE CLAUSE** to hide the expired data, i don`t know what is my problem in my query.

```
public function getList($end_date)
{
    $sql = "SELECT depo.id, depo.serial, depo.amount, depo.rate,
                depo.amount_rate, depo.acc_number, depo.status,
                depo.provider, depo.company, comp.company_name, depo.date ,
                pro.provider_name, depo.member_id, depo.ticket_id, 
                depo.open_balance, depo.image, depo.note, 
                depo.latest_balance, u.username
    FROM deposit as depo
    LEFT JOIN companies as comp ON comp.id = depo.company
    LEFT JOIN provider as pro ON pro.id = depo.provider
    LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = depo.user_id
    WHERE depo.status = '1' AND depo.date > '. $end_date . ' ";
    //echo $sql;
    return ($this->db->query($sql)->result());
}
```

Comment: if `depo.date` has date data type, just simply use mysql where depo.date is greater than `now` minus interval 7 day. then you'll get the records for the past seven days

Comment: but if you want php to supply the day, it's supposed to be a date that's behind today so it's not addition but subtraction, to today minus seven days

Comment: @Kevin like this sir ** WHERE depo.status = '1' AND depo.date > NOW() - interval 7days " ** ?

Comment: no `INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: @Kevin like this depo.date > NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY ?

Comment: from now until last 7 days ago, so `NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`, subtraction

Comment: @Kevin no output

Comment: @Kevin in there if 7 days I want to hide da data, like my screenshot the redmark.